# Override in while creating new instance of class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I know you can do that in java... i was wondering how to make the same approach using c# or getting the same result with different solution

```
new SomeClass() {
    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        // Do what you want
    }
};
```

Comment: In C#, an overridable member needs to be marked as `virtual` or `abstract` in the base class. There is no procedure to override a method during the instantiation of a class runtime.

Comment: As the answer will be about `[c#] I am removing `[java]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are the one defining the class, you could use lambda expressions/delegates to achieve what you are trying to accomplish:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Action someMethod { get; set; }
}
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var someClassInstance =
        new SomeClass()
        {
            someMethod =
            ()=>
            {
                // do what you want.
            }
        };

        someClassInstance.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you only want to allow setting the lambda once, use a constructor parameter like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public readonly Action someMethod;

    public SomeClass(Action someMethod) { this.someMethod = someMethod; }
}
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var someClassInstance =
        new SomeClass
        (
            someMethod:
            ()=>
            {
                // do what you want.
            }
        );

        someClassInstance.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Lastly, if you are truly trying to override behavior, supply a default implementation for the lambda by setting it in a default constructor in either version:

```
public SomeClass()
{
    this.someMethod = this.defaultSomeMethod;
}
private void defaultSomeMethod()
{
}
```

**UPDATE**:

If you want to access the public members of the class instance that you are adding the method to add the following constructor overload to the constructor approach:

```
    public SomeClass(Action<SomeClass> someMethod) { this.someMethod = ()=>someMethod(this); }
```

And then use it like so:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public readonly Action someMethod;

    public SomeClass(Action<SomeClass> someMethod) { this.someMethod = ()=>someMethod(this); }
    public SomeClass(Action someMethod) { this.someMethod = someMethod; }
    public SomeClass()
    {
        this.someMethod = this.defaultSomeMethod;
    }
    private void defaultSomeMethod()
    {
    }
    public void SomeOtherMethod() {}
}
public class Program
{
    static void YMain()
    {
        var someClassInstance =
        new SomeClass
        (
            someMethod :
            @this=>
            {
                @this.SomeOtherMethod();
                // do other stuff
            }
        );

        someClassInstance.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! Very nice explanation, i was wondering what if I'm not the one defining the class... and the predefined class has a virtual method, is there a way to override it without inheriting from the predefined class?

Comment: @EsamSherif No.  You would not be able to override the method without inheriting from the class.  However, you could create an intermediate of the class, override their method with a method that forwarded the call to a delegate with the same signature and then apply the technique in my answer.  The approach would be a method variation of the adapter pattern that is often used to conform third party components to a different interface or set of constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between Java and C# regarding class methods is that in Java all methods are virtual by default while in C# there are all sealed by default.

This is a design choice (in C#) motivated by the fact that when you are the designer of a class you know which part of your public API your want the consumer of your class to be able to change and which part you don't want them to.

In fact in Java it is more or less a design flaw to have all methods be virtual since it breaks the principle of isolation.

No back to your question, the answer by @tyree-jackson (i.e. using delegates) has useful insight. But in fact you could get rid of the class altogether since a delegate (here an instance of Action) is already a reference type and can be passed around in method calls.

Comment: The fact that Java is virtual by default does not have much bearing on what the author is trying to accomplish.  The ability to override a virtual method at instantiation time could be a useful feature in C# even without switching to a *Virtual by default* design.  Of course, we can use delegates to obtain similar functionality, but you have to explicitly instrument your class to support this.

Answer (score 0):

I may have got the question slightly wrong here but...

Suggesting you have some base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass()
{
    public abstract Method0();

    public virtual Method1()
    {
    }

    public Method2()
    {
    }
}
```

Here if you have a class inheriting the base class, you can override the methods by:

```
public class SomeClass : BaseClass
{
    public override Method0()
    {
    }

    public override Method1()
    {
    }

    public new Method2()
    {
    }
}
```

Here if you have an instance of SomeClass you can call all the overriden (and new) methods. However if you have an instance of BaseClass you can call the overriden but not new methods. So:

```
SomeClass test = new SomeClass();
test.Method0();// Calls overriden Method0
test.Method1();// Calls overriden Method1
test.Method2();// Calls new Method2

BaseClass test2 = new SomeClass();
test2.Method0();// Calls overriden Method0
test2.Method1();// Calls overriden Method1
test2.Method2();// Calls BaseClass's Method2
```

Hopefully this helps